DocumentClient with Managed Identity for cosmos DB CRUD operations
We are using cosmos DB in our project through DocumentClient.
Currently we are authenticating using Connection string of cosmos db.
We are trying to migrate to Managed Identity for authentication and avoid using connection string.
Need help in finding resources where Managed Identity has been used alongside DocumentClient

On top of what Sajeet mentions, DocumentClient (V2) is being fully deprecated in August 31, 2024. Consider migrating.

No, it is not supported with the DocumentClient. You need to use the V3 and above .Net SDK to do the same.
TokenCredential servicePrincipal = new ClientSecretCredential(
    "<azure-ad-tenant-id>",
    "<client-application-id>",
    "<client-application-secret>");
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("<account-endpoint>", servicePrincipal);

